# Facebook Notification redirect to external URL

Tags: android, ios, facebook, apache-flex, air

We are trying to implement a simple solution to our website developed via Flex and mobile apps developed using Adobe Air.

1) Our users would like to import their facebook friends onto website via www.ourwebsite.com and also via the **Ourwebsite** android, ios & blackberry apps.
2) We want to use the Facebook Requests dialog which allows users to select their friends and send multiple invitations at a time
3) When the recepient clicks on the notification he receives

- in case of web, it should direct the notification recipient to www.ourwebsite.com
- in case of mobile app, it should re-direct to respective appstore to download our app.

We tried several configurations but it's not working for us.

As previously said we have developed our website using Adobe Flex and our Mobiles apps run using Adobe Air. Do we need to install the Facebook native SDK's into our code?

Strangely the exact same requirement is working for www.naaptol.com and 9lessons.info.
But we're unable to achieve the same technique.
Can anyone guide us or advise if we're missing any important aspect of Facebook App & its policies.

Thank you.
Sai Krishna

Answer (score 0):

So if I think I am understanding this right, you want to be able to open a link differently based upon the platform they are on.  Here is some js that will do it for ios and android.  If they have your app installed it will launch the app, otherwise it will send them to the app store

```
// if iPod / iPhone, display install app prompt
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad);?/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {

var store_loc = "itms://itunes.com/apps/youriOSApp";
var href = "yourPrefix://";

var is_android = false;

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
    store_loc = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.your.app";
    is_android = true;
}
var app_loc = href;
if (is_android) {
    var w = null;
    try {
        w = window.open(app_loc, '_blank');
    } catch (e) {
        //   no exception
    }
    if (w) {
        window.close();
    } else {
        window.location = store_loc;
    }
} else {
    var timeout = null;
    window.location.replace(app_loc);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        "use strict";
        window.location = store_loc;
    }, 300);
    onblur = function () {
        "use strict";
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you CodeMonkey. How about the first case? How to redirect a facebook notification click to www.ourwebsite.com. What all settings are required in the Facebook App page?

Comment: Try adding  redirect_uri=www.example.com  to your site url in fb settings

Comment: It just doesn't go to my site. It keeps searching for my site url in Facebook search box and dies there. Is there any SSL requirement and also any app basic requirement that it has to be used by X number of ppl and only then redirecting option gets activated?

Comment: I'm not really sure on the facebook stuff, I just knew for sure how to filter out different platforms when they get to your site